# pass csv file in variable between two php files

Tags: php, file

I am trying to create a simple 'upload csv file web form in php' That takes a csv file, and converts to json. File 1, `finder.php`

Here is /`finder.php` (file #1, the web form)

```
 echo '<div class="wrap"><h1>Step 1.) Upload the First .CSV file below. So, we can use it as data!</h1>';
 echo '<form action="/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="csv" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></form>';
```

Here is file 2, the functionality; /`upload.php` I had it working with absolute file paths; but I need it to be a variable from my upload page, to my upload handler.

```
<?php

    echo "<h2>Uploading....</h2>";

    $file= fopen('assets/files/locationsCSV.csv', 'r'); #needs to be variable from upload screen
    $csv= file_get_contents($file);
    $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));     
    file_put_contents("assets/files/locationsCSV.json",json_encode($array)); #needs to be variable from upload screen

?>
```

Comment: So upload provided file, get path to it and use this path. __Manuals__ how to upload file with php are __everywhere__.

Comment: Did you Google "PHP upload file example"? You should find everything you need

Comment: You should know how this works from your previous question already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769444/convert-uploaded-csv-file-to-new-json-file

Answer (score 1):

It is available in the `$_FILES` array.

```
$myCsv = $_FILES["csv"]
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) is an example